# Bringing in other local scripts with Component package manager?

Tags: components, package-managers

I'm just getting started with [Component](https://github.com/component/component) package manager. I understand that I can `require` in other local modules by adding the module to the `local` key in the `component.json` file, but what if I don't want to treat every file as a module?

In the (very minimal) documentation for Component, it's developer TJ says that I can add any other relevant scripts (that live in the same directory) to the `scripts` array. And yet, on doing so, I'm unable to `require` or reference any of the peripheral scripts' methods from my `main` file.

The `require` method fails on trying to load in the script, and any attempt to reference the methods or variables from that script from the 'bootstrap' file are futile. My `build.js` shows that the script has been compiled in, but I just can't seem to figure out the correct way to reference it from other scripts...

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought I'd post the answer to this question so anybody with the same problem can find it quickly/painlessly.

The answer is to reference the script with a pointer to it's current directory like so:

```
var script = require('./script.js');
```

Note the `./` at the beginning of the file name.

An easy mistake to make/rectify.